# How to parse an html node containing multiple tags?

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I'm able to reach the node I want to extract but couldn't figure out how to separate different tags within the node.

p.s. I'm OK with regular expression; just curious if a simpler way with *Html Agility Pack* exists or not.

Code:

```
...
...
HtmlNodeCollection nodes = webContent.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='node-name']/ul/li");

foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes) {
    String link = ???; // extract the http link here (href)
    String text = ???; // extract the inner text here
    String nums = ???; // extract the content of <small> tag here
    ...
}
```

html sample:

```
...
...
<ul class="some-class-name">
  <li>
    <a href="http://link-1.com">text for link 1<small>1</small></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://link-2.org">text for link 2<small>2</small></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://link-3.net">text for link 3<small>3</small></a>
  </li>
</ul>
...
...
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `HtmlAgilityPack` (it's kinda... dead now) instead of a more modern library like AngleSharp?

Comment: WOW, last I had used `AngleSharp` (years ago now) it was utilizing `HtmlAgilityPack`. That *doesn't* seem to be the case anymore. Kudos to the `AngleSharp` group and thanks for bringing this to light, @Dai.

Comment: @Dai: are you sure this is the case these days ? It was true years ago, when we then switched to AngleSharp... but it was revamped and seems active: [1](https://html-agility-pack.net/) and [2](https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either Element(s) or Descendants, from the native API.
Keep in mind that you can use extensions such as [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack.CssSelectors.NetCore/) to enable css selector querying, which in my understanding is the preferred (and easiest) way.

Follows a code snippet:

```
    //https://stackoverflow.com/q/70203208/1219280
    var doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(@"
        <ul class='some -class-name'>
          <li>
            <a href = 'http://link-1.com' > text for link 1<small>1</small></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href = 'http://link-2.org' > text for link 2<small>2</small></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href = 'http://link-3.net' > text for link 3<small>3</small></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
    ");

    Console.WriteLine("-------------------- Using Element(s) -------------------------");

    //using Element(s), queries children in the next level only
    var ul = doc.DocumentNode.Element("ul");
    var lis = ul.Elements("li");
    foreach(var li in lis)
    {
        var a = li.Element("a");
        var href = a?.GetAttributeValue("href");
        var smallText = a.Element("small")?.InnerText;

        Console.WriteLine($"a href: [{href}] small: [{smallText}]");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("-------------------- Using Descendants -------------------------");

    //using Descendants
    var anchors = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("a");
    foreach(var a in anchors)
    {
        var href = a?.GetAttributeValue("href");
        var smallText = a.Element("small")?.InnerText;

        Console.WriteLine($"a href: [{href}] small: [{smallText}]");
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]